# Array values being set for everything (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

In my code below, I am having an issue where I add the customer name to one room, but instead it adds the customer to every room. I can't figure out what in my code the issue is. I have tried removing the procedure but that still produced the same problem.

```
package test;

import java.util.*;

public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String choice, custName = "";

        int roomNum = 1;


        String[] hotel = new String[12];
        String[] customer = new String[12];

            hotelInitialise(hotel);
            custInitialise(customer);


            while ( roomNum < hotel.length-1 ) {

                for (int i = 0; i < hotel.length-1; i++) {

                    System.out.println("This is the Hotel Menu. Please choose from the following options:\n");
                    System.out.println("A: " + "This will add a new entry\n");
                    System.out.println("V: " + "View all rooms\n");


                    choice = input.next().toUpperCase();

                    if (choice.equals("A")) {

                        System.out.println("Enter room number(1-10)");
                        roomNum =input.nextInt();

                        System.out.println("Enter name for room " + roomNum + " : " ) ;
                        custName = input.next();

                        addNewBooking(hotel, custName);
                        System.out.println(" ");

                    }

                    if (choice.equals("V")) {

                        seeAllRooms(hotel, custName);

                    }

                }

            }
}

// When the program loads it will assign all the values of the array as being empty
private static void hotelInitialise( String hotelRef[] ) {

    for (int x = 0; x < 11; x++){

        hotelRef[x] = "Room " + x + " is empty.";
    }

    System.out.println( "Welcome to the Summer Tropic Hotel.\n");

}

private static void custInitialise (String custRef[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        custRef[i] = ", no customer has occupied this room";    
    }
}

private static void addNewBooking(String hotel[], String customer) {

   for (int x =1; x <11; x++) {

        if (hotel[x].equals("Room " + hotel[x] + " is empty."))
            System.out.println("Room " + x + " is empty.");
        else {
            System.out.println("Room " + x + " is occupied by "+ customer);

        }

    }
}

private static void seeAllRooms(String hotel[], String customer) {
   for (int i = 0; i < hotel.length-1; i++) {

        int j=0;
        String custName = customer;
        hotel[j]= custName;

        if (hotel[i].equals("Room " + i + " is empty."))
            System.out.println("Room " + i + " is empty.");
        else {
            System.out.println("Room " + i + " is occupied by "+ hotel[j] + ".");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you suggest any value of a `String` for which the expression `hotel[x].equals("Room " + hotel[x] + " is empty.")` would return `true`?

Comment: You have `if (hotel[i].equals("Room is empty."))` in your `seeAllRooms`. This doesn't match the other checks where you check the hotel number. Try changing this to `if (hotel[i].equals("Room " + hotel[i] + " is empty."))`. Although, checking a String like that seems cumbersome. Couldn't NULL mean it's empty instead?

Comment: Please review this code yourself. Test each method one by one because none of them are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `addNewBooking` method you have this line:

```
if (hotel[x].equals("Room " + hotel[x] + " is empty."))
```

However hotel[x] has a value of "Room x is empty" e.g. hotel[1] is "Room 1 is empty" So the final check is becoming "hotel[x].equals(Room Room x is empty is empty.)" which is never equals to your hotel[x]

You have to change your code to

```
if (hotel[x].equals("Room " + x + " is empty."))
//do something there like add the booking
```